# “I come from France”

Tags: grammar

Is "france" the direct object in the sentence?

"I" is doing the verb "come" but is France receiving the verb? The grammar book says that direct object answers who? or what? questions but France does not so I'm confused.

Comment: In some analyses, 'come from' is a single lexeme, a multi-word verb, here with DO _France_. Compare French 'j'habite Lyons, 'habiter' = 'live in'.  In others, 'from France' is a prepositional phrase, here a necessary 'completer' (again, some might say 'complement')  of the verb 'come'.

Comment: Please don’t repost. https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/265607/41273

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no object in that sentence. "from France" is a prepositional phrase acting as an adverb, in other words it gives more information about the verb 'to come'. This is similar to "He is coming home" or even "he is coming home from France" which still has no object since 'home' and 'France' are locations.

In fact 'to come' is usually an *intransitive* verb  which means that it does not take an object at all.

The Macmillan Online Dictionary has this entry for *come* which gives several different meanings only one of which is described as *transitive*. The transitive meaning of *come* is

> **1b** to move or travel a particular distance to where you are

with the examples

> Have you come *a long way*?

> They’ve come *about 10 miles* from the next village.

I have added italicisation to indicate the direct object phrases in those examples. As you can see they contain a measure of distance which "I come from France" does not. You shoud also be able to see that, in the second one, 'from the next village' is another prepositional phrase acting as an adverb like "from France" which gives more information about the verb 'come'.

All the other meanings are described as *intransitive*

Comment: So is "I" the subject? Another answer says it's the object because it answers the who? question. Who comes from France? "I" do.

Comment: I'm not aware of any scholarly treatments regarding 'a long way' in 'I've come a long way' as a DO; it's a measure phrase used adverbially. The difficulty is that 'I've come' (in the 'I've journeyed / contrived to cover' sense) cannot stand alone. The 'I've arrived' sense is different.

Comment: @user404972, asking "who?" is not a good way to distinguish subjects and objects. In simple sentences, the subject tells you "who did the action" and the object tells you "who was the action done to", but both questions start with "who". Furthermore there are constructions where these questions will not correctly distinguish subject and object.

Comment: @user404972 There are only three parts to the sentence, The subject 'I', the verb 'come' and the prepositional phrase 'from France'. If you omit 'from France' you get the grammatically correct but almost meaningless sentence "I come".